# Make the URL of the webpage permanent

Tags: javascript, html, url-routing

I have a webpage (localhost).  When I type its URL in the browser I am making it redirect to another webpage using Javascript.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function wa() {
        window.location = "http://www.anyWebsite.com";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="wa()">
```

As a result the URL in the web browser also changes. The only thing I need here is that the URL should not change.

Comment: For security reasons that should be clear if you think about it, that is not possible.

Comment: @SLaks well I suppose that's true, but if it's a page with any interest in security it'll try as hard as it can to break out of the frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the other page into an `<iframe>` or `<frameset>` that covers your entire page.

Note that you will not be able to display the other page's title.

Also note that many websites (such as StackOverflow) will prevent this for security reasons.

Comment: I will personally come to your house and hit you in the head with a baseball bat if you ever do this to me while I'm browsing a web page.  I can't think of any good use case for this that is not abusive.

Comment: There are surely many good reasons. For example, we process the user's request and discover that we want to send him to a different page. But we don't want to waste the round trip to send a redirect message, get it back, and then display the new page. It's more efficient to just send the new page under the existing url.

Comment: @Jay: Then use AJAX on an existing page, or something like that.  But what you're describing sounds like premature optimization anyway, a lot more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Google Image Search does this.

Comment: @Robertharvey Well, I don't want to get into an argument about it. But it's only a "premature optimization" if it is done prematurely. Such a redirect takes one line of code, while building an Ajax structure to redesign the screen dynamically would surely be non-trivial. And the concept is exactly the same as the whole design philosophy behind Java servlets, or ASP's RegisterRoute: figure out what the user is asking, decide which page provides the answer, and send that page. Are there drawbacks? Sure. But "has drawbacks" does not mean it should never, ever be done.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer!! Not possible

Page will refresh every time when you will change `window.location`

Answer (score 0):

Not possible for security reasons, users should see what URL they are at.

There are workarounds though - make an IFrame for the whole page and set the location there or dynamically load the page and update from different location.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot believe I'm about to suggest using iframes, but you're easiest solution is indeed iframes.

Create an iframe that's 100%x100%, and when the window loads set the location of the iframe to your new url. The location bar will (should?) stay the same while the page appears to have moved onto a different location.

iframes: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp